# NullReferenceException when creating new instance of class

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, nuget, nullreferenceexception, webdeploy

Long time reader, first time poster.

So I have a VisualStudio2010 asp.net project (.net 4.0). The project runs perfectly when I run it through Visual Studio. If manually copy the files to my test server, it also works perfectly.

The problem is when I publish the site through Web Deploy, I get a NullReferenceException whenever my code tries to instantiate a new class provided by a nuget package.

In this example, MySql.* is a package installed via nuget. The packages directory is included in the project.

```
Imports MySql.Data
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class TestClass

    Public Sub Load()
        Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter() ' NullReferenceException thrown here.
    End Sub
End Class
```

Seriously, any help would be great! Thanks.

### Update: Issue solved

So I solved my problem by changing the following setting: Project Properties -> Package/Publish Web > Items to deploy Change from "Only file needed to run this project" to "All files in this project"

That effectively did the same thing as my manual push from before.

What I gather was happening was my compiled assemblies were being transfered but never loaded in the .net virtual machine on the IIS server. Weird. Please correct me, I'd like to know a bit more.

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace?

Comment: Not really. The stack trace I'd post would not apply to the example I posted earlier.

Comment: You should add this as an answer and mark it as the answer (after 24 hours). Otherwise, this question will remain "unanswered" on the site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved my problem by changing the following setting: Project Properties -> Package/Publish Web > Items to deploy Change from "Only file needed to run this project" to "All files in this project"

That effectively did the same thing as my manual push from before.

What I gather was happening was my compiled assemblies were being transfered but never loaded in the .net virtual machine on the IIS server. Weird. Please correct me, I'd like to know a bit more.